# Asp.Net 4.x UseJwtBearerAuthentication events onTokenValidated

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.6.1

I have web api project (ASP.Net 4.7) where i am Jwt Bearer Token for authentication and i would like to hook to an event when token is successfully validated call user information endpoint and add custom logic and add claims to identity.

I know we can do something similar with dotnet core https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-jwt-saving-bearer-token-as-claim/

Asp.Net 4.x

```
        var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(issuer + "/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(), new HttpDocumentRetriever());
        var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = "Any",
                ValidIssuer = issuer,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                {
                    return discoveryDocument.SigningKeys;
                }
            },

        });
```

Please advise ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have a similar requirement for an ASP.NET 4.x project.